# Is there an event called while a jQuery UI draggable element is being reverted to its original position?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a draggable element using jQuery UI, and have a function attached the drag event that gets continuously called with the element's position while the user is dragging it.

I also have *revert: true* set on this element, so when the user stops dragging the element springs back to its original position. Is there a way I can attach a listener to perform the same functionality as when it's being manually moved?

I can't see anything specifically related to the revert property in the docs, so if that's not possible is there a more general event called while an element is moving?

Thanks!

Comment: there is nothing specific to move element to its old position, but you can store there positions on document.ready

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears there's nothing in the API for this, so I've had to hack it using setInterval.

```
var revertInterval;

var revertEvent = function(el) {
    revertInterval = setInterval(function() {
        // Do things
        // e.g. console.log(el.position().top);
    }, 5);
}


$('#draggable').draggable({
    revert: function() {
        revertEvent($(this));
        return true;
    },
    stop: function() {
        clearInterval(revertInterval);
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

the revert is accept function as follow

```
revert: function(param){}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mori57/Xpscw/)

Comment: Thanks, but the function it accepts is to add logic for whether or not it should revert. It doesn't pass in the event or ui object.